# How to fetch CoreData result for only selected row in swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift5

How can I fetch the CoreData value something like in SQL `SELECT * FROM user where username="something"`

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let db = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request : NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username='\(usernameLabel.text!)'")
    request.predicate = predicate

    do{
        let result = try db.fetch(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
        var get_email : String = ""

        for item in result {
            if let email = (item as AnyObject).value(forKey: "email") as? String {
                get_email.append(email)
            }

        }
        emailTextField.text = get_email

    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print(error)
    }
```

in above code, the output will be something like `tester1@tester.comtester2@tester.com` It actually fetch entire email column.

Comment: Are you sure the username field is unique? You'd be better using placeholders rather than string interpolation in your predicate but otherwise it looks basically okay.

Comment: @StephenDarlington oh thanks. I think i got the problem. I forgot to do duplication checking on the registration page

Comment: Please, the syntax `(item as AnyObject).value(forKey: "email") as? String` is horrible. Annotate the fetch request `NSFetchRequest<User>`, delete `as! [NSManagedObject]` and get the string value `if let email = item.email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predicate looks fine (well, you'd be better using placeholders rather than string interpolation) so the most likely problem is that the username field isn't unique.